# Black model with negative strike price

Tags: derivatives, swaption, black76

Whats the issue if we try to price a swaption with a negative strike using Black model?

Comment: In this case, there is no optionality, and the valuation becomes trivial.

Comment: And mechanically, you will also have log of a negative number in the d_i's, so the calculator is going to scream.